# Nginx Reverse Proxy non listening domain catch all

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, catch-all

Using nginx as a reverse proxy I have noted that if a site is pointed at the server but does not actually exist you get served with an existing site on the server rather than a domain cannot be found message or similar.

**ie** say your config block is listening for portal.test.org the user points there **cname** to the nginx system but with the domain header of **smartportal.test.org**

or say the they point a site like **portal.test2.org**

Could someone direct me on the following

a. How nginx decides which site to return when it does not exist as a virtual host
b. How to catch any domain that are not specified and return a default page that tells users this domain does not exist on this host

Hope someone can help I have tried googling but I think sometimes its knowing the correct terms.

Many thanks

Answer (score 3):

you should use `default_server` parameter of [listen](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#listen) directive and [server_name](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#server_name) directive.

your questions

- How nginx decides which site to return when it does not exist as a virtual host

  > listen [default_server]
  >
  > If the directive has the default_server parameter, then the enclosing
  >   server {...} block will be the default server for the address:port
  >   pair. This is useful for name-based virtual hosting where you wish to
  >   specify the default server block for hostnames that do not match any
  >   server_name directives. If there are no directives with the
  >   default_server parameter, then the default server will be the first
  >   server block in which the address:port pair appears.
  >
  > ---
  >
  > server_name
  >
  > This directive performs two actions:
  >
  > Compares the Host header of the incoming HTTP request against the
  >   server { ... } blocks in the Nginx configuration files and selects the
  >   first one that matches. This is how virtual servers are defined.
  >   Server names are processed in the following order:
  >
  > 1.- full, static names
  >
  > 2.- names with a wildcard at the start of the name — *.example.com
  >
  > 3.- names with a wildcard at the end of the name — www.example.*
  >
  > 4.- names with regular expressions
  >
  > If there is no match, a server { ... } block in
  >   the configuration file will be used based on the following order:
  >
  > 1.- the
  >   server block with a matching listen directive marked as
  >   [default|default_server]
  >
  > 2.- the first server block with a matching listen
  >   directive (or implicit listen 80;)
- How to catch any domain that are not specified and return a default page that tells users this domain does not exist on this host

  > ```
  > server {
  >   listen 1.2.3.4:80 default_server;
  >   server_name _ "";
  >   location / {
  >     alias /var/www/html/domain-does-not-exists.html; 
  >    }
  > }
  >
  > server {
  >   listen 1.2.3.4:80 ;
  >   server_name portal.test.org;
  >   location / {
  >       ... your site ...
  >    }
  > }
  > ```